# Redirect all .org .ca .net domains to main domain

Tags: apache, redirect, apache2

Our server setup is apache2 on ubuntu.

We have purchased example.com, example.ca, example.org and example.net I am trying to redirect all versions of these examples to our https://www.example.com while trying to be as DRY as possible. I have found many examples redirecting http to https or www. to non www. however I can't find much on a general catch all rule to send:

```
http://www.example.ca
http://example.ca
https://example.ca
https://www.example.ca
```

(The same as above with .org, .net and .com)

All to https://www.example.com

I have added the below rules to our 000-default.conf file. I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to write these rules to better redirect to https://www.example.com and I am also looking for help with redirecting all https requests for all examples to https://www.example.com. Please let me know if I am out to lunch or not.

Thanks for the help in advance.

**000-default.conf**

```
# Redirect .net to .com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.net
  ServerAlias example.net
  RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.(net)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>

# Redirect .org to .com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.org
  ServerAlias example.org
  RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.(org)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>

# Redirect .ca to .com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.ca
  ServerAlias example.ca
  RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.(ca)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>

# Redirect back to example.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
</VirtualHost>

# Enable ssl certifications
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile path to chain
    SSLCertificateKeyFile path to key
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you have one SSL cert which includes all domain names?

Comment: Yes we have one.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Redirect anything http:// to https://www.example.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com example.net www.example.net example.org www.example.org example.ca www.example.ca
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com example.net www.example.net example.org www.example.org example.ca www.example.ca
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile path to chain
    SSLCertificateKeyFile path to key
    RewriteEngine on
    # Redirect anything not www.example.com to https://www.example.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
</VirtualHost>
```

After you confirm it works as expected, replace `302` with `301`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This looks like is a much cleaner solution. While all urls are redirected to https://www.example.com. I am still not redirected if I type in https://www.example.ca. Perhaps there is an issue with our certs